# New line pressing "Return" key with asp:TextBox

Tags: asp.net, textbox, newline

I have an `asp:TextBox` in an ajax popup panel. I've searched for a way to make a new line when the user presses the "Enter/Return" key, but nothing has worked so far.

Here is my TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CommentaireSaveTxt" MaxLength="4999" TextMode="MultiLine" 
             Width="250px" Height="100px" runat="server" />
```

I've read that sometimes the enter key defaults to a button without any indication that it will do so, but none of my ajax panel's buttons events are firing. As far as I know, nothing happens at all. I suspect there might be some kind of problem with my textbox being in the panel.

Here is my AJAX:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnSauvegarder_ModalPopupExtender" 
    runat="server" TargetControlID="DummySauvegarder"  
    PopupControlID="btnSauvegarder_ModalPopupExtender_PNL" 
    CancelControlID="ButtonCancel"  
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" 
    Enabled="True" DynamicServicePath="" />

<asp:Panel ID="btnSauvegarder_ModalPopupExtender_PNL" 
    Style="display: none;" 
    CssClass="modalPNL" 
    runat="server"
    meta:resourcekey="btnSauvegarder_ModalPopupExtender_PNLResource1">

    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
               <img src="..\Images\IconQuestion.png" alt="Question" />
               <asp:TextBox ID="CommentaireSaveTxt" MaxLength="4999" Rows="50"
                            TextMode="MultiLine" Width="250px" 
                            Height="100px" runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblMessageSauvegarder" runat="server" 
                           meta:resourcekey="lblMessageSauvegarderResource1">
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonOkSauvegarder" runat="server" Text="OK"  
                    OnClick="ButtonOkSauvegarder_Click" 
                    meta:resourcekey="ButtonOkDeleteResource1" />

        <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancelSauvegarder" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  
                    meta:resourcekey="ButtonCancelResource2" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

EDIT : 
After testing...
For some reason, it doesn't work anywhere in my page. When looking at the generated html code from the browser, the textarea does not have any property for "AcceptsReturn" to true. I don't know if that can help anyone in finding the trouble.

My whole page is contained into `UpdatePanel` and `ContentTemplate` if that has any matters. I really am out of clue with what my problem is. I tested with a partner and he has no problem making it work in his projet (another website).

Comment: Can you post the markup of your AJAX popup panel?

Comment: Sure, I edited my post with it. Sorry for the soso formating.

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?  I think this might be a fault where the default button click is picking up even on textarea controls

Comment: Target framework is .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: I have formatted your code, it was hard to follow.

Comment: Ah, ok, in that case ignore me @user3722883 - I think that was a fault in either 1.1 or 2.0.

Comment: No problem, thanks anyways @freefaller. And yeah, my bad on the format, the copy/paste kind of messed up. Thank you.

Comment: The resulting markup is a `<textarea ... />` and not an `<input ... />`, correct? A textarea doesn't need any "AcceptsReturn" or the like - it simply allows multiple lines of text, and return is a newline by default functionality. For return _not_ to work, there would have to be some script grabbing and sitting on that particular key press. Try debugging via your browser with scripts off and see if it then allows lines as per normal.

Comment: That was it, @Mike Guthrie. I'm working on someone else's website and he chose to cancel "enter" key press so it wouldn't submit the page if the user pressed it. I removed it and changed `UseSubmitBehavior` to `false` for every buttons so it wont submit if the user presses "enter". Thank you!